# Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery

Hi
    i have used the Jquery menu and jquery lightbox(sexylightbox plugin) for my website http://anandhvpm.abcz8.com/jQuery/,  but there is some conflict that doesn't allow to work other.If disabled any one of them, the other will work very.In the url, you can see the menu part jquery is working. In the below text **"Click Me to See Document Proof"**, if we click a lightbox need to open and show the image but due to conflict it doesn't shows up anything.So please suggest any ideas to overcome jquery conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at noConflict method, if it can help you.

[Jquery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have tried with it, still it was not working out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not ideal solution, but why don't you try with a different lightbox plug-in.  If it works with another one great! If not you can guess the problem is with the menu.